# What is wrong with my data constructor import/use, when ghc suggestion is to add constructor to import list?

Tags: haskell

I have the following line of code where I'm trying to extract the internal raw type so I  can work with it directly:

```
SDL.Internal.Types.Window (rawWindow) = window
```

My import looks like:

```
import qualified SDL.Internal.Types     (Window)
```

The error I get is below; it seems I'm already doing what it suggests.

```
%    /home/brandon/workspace/hico/src/Hico/Game.hs:273:5: error:
        Not in scope: data constructor `SDL.Internal.Types.Window'
        Perhaps you want to add `Window' to the import list
        in the import of `SDL.Internal.Types' (src/Hico/Game.hs:34:1-48).
        |
    273 |     SDL.Internal.Types.Window (rawWindow) = window
        |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The content of the `Types.hs` file is very short, and doesn't seem to offer any clues to me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module SDL.Internal.Types
  ( Joystick(..)
  , Window(..)
  , Renderer(..)
  ) where

import Data.Data (Data)
import Data.Typeable
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

import qualified SDL.Raw as Raw

newtype Joystick = Joystick { joystickPtr :: Raw.Joystick }
  deriving (Data, Eq, Generic, Ord, Show, Typeable)

newtype Window = Window (Raw.Window)
  deriving (Data, Eq, Generic, Ord, Show, Typeable)

-- | An SDL rendering device. This can be created with 'SDL.Video.createRenderer'.
newtype Renderer = Renderer Raw.Renderer
  deriving (Data, Eq, Generic, Ord, Show, Typeable)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By writing

```
import qualified SDL.Internal.Types     (Window)
```

you are importing only the type Window, and none of its constructors. To import a data type and some limited subset of its constructors, one writes (using Maybe as an example because I don't know SDL's types):

```
import Prelude (Maybe(Just))
```

This import would allow you to use Maybe in type annotations, and use the Just constructor to pattern-match or to create new values of type Maybe a, but you would not be able to use Nothing in either of those circumstances.

Note that the above would be a very unusual thing to do: normally you want either all of a type's constructors (so that you can build and consume any value of that type), or none of them (so that your functions can receive or return values of that type, constructed and consumed by other functions).

If you want all of a type's constructors, you can use the exact syntax used in the module export definition you listed: `(..)` means "all of the constructors of this type":

```
import qualified SDL.Internal.Types     (Window(..))
```

Comment: I strongly recommend either exporting/importing *all* constructors (using `(..)` syntax), or *none* of them, except under very unusual circumstances. Limiting to only some of them invites partial functions, and listing them explicitly is just extra work up front and when changing the type. The only time I might consider exporting just some constructors would be if others are used only transiently for internal purposes, as in some formulations of red-black trees.

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed. I've edited the question to point out that it's pretty weird to import a subset of constructors.